# Does searchkick automatically update the index after model has been created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

When I include searchkick in an AR model like so:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick # callbacks: :async
end
```

Is the index synced automatically when I create a new Dog model, or do I have to implement this is an `after_commit` callback? I found the docs to be somewhat ambiguous on that point and I have not been able to verify this behavior in my tests.

Comment: If it operates like elasticsearch you will need to create an index for that model first and then it will automatically keep track of changes via callbacks behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, the index is automatically created.

Comment: A fast way to check is to import all your records and then modify one and perform the search!  See if it finds the record based on the updated value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should auto reindex. Unless you have something blocking them.

`By default, all records are indexed. To control which records are indexed, use the should_index? method together with the search_import scope.`

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#indexing